# Dynamic UIViews in Obj-c + Cocoa touch

Tags: objective-c, iphone, cocoa-touch, uiview

I need a way of creating a UIView dynamically. Thus, the parent class could look for say a count of array items, and create UIViews on the fly of the amount of items in the array.

The views need to be allocated dynamically, do I can't create them on the fly.

Can you help?

Answer (score 2):

You can create them anytime.

```
UIView *myView = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:myFrameRect]
```

You can call this from within a loop, store the pointer in another array for further use or whatever you want. Just remember to release them when you are done. Otherwise you will be in a memory issue.

Comment: Not really what I was looking for, I need to create pointers dynamically, so the count in an array (NSArray) to be the number of UIViews created is the number of items in the array, and then I need to be able to refer to the UIViews by name (pointer).

Answer (score 0):

I think what you want is this (according to the response on taskinoor answer).

```
NSMutableArray* array = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
for (int i =0; i < 10; i++){
   UIView *myView = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0.0, 5.0 + (i * 20), 15.0, 15.0)];
   [array addObject:myView];    

}
```

When when you want one of those views just call

```
UIView* view = (UIView*)[array objectAtIndex:number];
```